# Sum of Multinomial Coefficients

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

Basically, I want to write a function to compute the following sum

$f(m,L):=\sum_{0\leq k_1,\cdots, k_n\leq m} \binom{m}{k_1,k_2,\cdots k_n}$ and $\mathrm{supp}(k)=L \subseteq \left \{ 1,...,n \right \}$

I wrote the following function but it doesn't work:

```
L = {1, 2, 4, 5};
f[m, L] := Return[For[i = 1, i <= m, i++, Total[Multinomial@@Take[L, i]]]];
f[3, L]
(*f[3, {1, 2, 4, 5}]*)
```

What am I missing? Thank you

EDIT: I added a condition to the indices $k$, which I forgot to mention earlier. $\mathrm{supp}(k)=L$ means that $L$ is the set of indices such that the components of the vector $k=(k_1,...,k_n)$ are nonzero.

Comment: Define functions like `f[m_, bigL_]` for a start.

Comment: Take a look at [Defining functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html) in the docs.

Comment: It's rude to delete a question I just took the time to answer.  Do you find no value in what I wrote?  (I undeleted this to comment but if you insist I will delete it again.)

Comment: I'm so sorry I didnt saw that you wrote an answer! I wouldnt have deleted the question. I figured out the same solution as you posted myself. Anyway I'll keep the question! I apologize once more!

Comment: Okay, no problem.  I'm glad you found your solution.  Please consider the bulleted points in my answer as well because they can save you a lot of of future frustration and/or wasted effort.  All but the use of `Total` are common beginner problems.  As for `Total` I'm not sure what you intended but either you don't understand what the `Total` function does or you placed it without thinking.  If you want a function that will add up any values that are given to it and then return that total when requested I can show you how.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your EDIT.  `Multinomial[3, 4, 0, 1] === Multinomial[3, 4, 1]` is already `True` so you don't have to manually remove zeros.  Do you mean something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sum is a little strange, because the multinomial coefficient makes sense only when $k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_n=m$.  I will assume this restriction is (implicitly) intended and that $n$ is *fixed.*  (If not, a variation of the following solution will work.)

Notice that the set

$$\{0 \le k_1 \le k_2 \le \ldots \le k_n \le m\}$$

is in one-to-one correspondence with the $n$ differences

$$(k_1, k_2-k_1, \ldots, k_n - k_{n-1}, m-k_n).$$

The elements of the latter are non-negative integers summing to $m$.  If we add $1$ to each, they will be *positive* and sum (obviously) to $m+n$.  The set of such sequences is obtained with `IntegerPartitions`.

Working backwards, then, we can invoke `IntegerPartitions`, subtract $1$ from all elements, apply `Multinomial`, and `Sum` what we have obtained.  This leads to the efficient and straightforward solution:

```
f[m_Integer, n_Integer] := 
   Sum[Multinomial @@ k, {k, # - ConstantArray[1, n] & /@ IntegerPartitions[m + n, {n}]}]
```

(Including `{n}` as an argument to `IntegerPartitions` causes the number of $k_i$ to be fixed at $n$.)

For example, `f[5,4]` adds up all such multinomial coefficients having $n=4$ terms summing to $m=5$:

$$\eqalign{
&\sum_{0 \le k_1\le k_2\le k_3\le k_4 \le 5}\binom{5}{k_1\ k_2\ k_3\ k_4} \\
&= \binom{5}{0\ 0\ 0\ 5} + \binom{5}{0\ 0\ 1\ 4} + \binom{5}{0\ 0\ 2\ 3}+ \binom{5}{0\ 1\ 1\ 3}+ \binom{5}{0\ 1\ 2\ 2}+ \binom{5}{1\ 1\ 1\ 2} \\
&= 1 + 5 + 10 + 20 + 30 + 60 \\
& = 126.
}$$

---

#### Edit

I have speculated (in comments below) that the role of `L` might be to limit the possible values of the $k_i$ to a set.  Specifically, this interpretation asks for the calculation of

$$\sum_{k_i \in L: 0\le k_1\le \ldots \le k_n \le m} \binom{m}{k_1\ k_2\ \ldots\ k_n}$$

where $m$, $n$, and $L$ are given. When $m$ is not too large, a simple way is to modify the preceding solution to include only those index vectors $(k_i)$ whose components lie in $L$:

```
f[m_Integer, n_Integer, support_List] := 
 With[{indexes = 
    Select[# - ConstantArray[1, n] & /@ IntegerPartitions[m + n, {n}], 
      Complement[#, support] == {} &]}, 
  Reap[Sum[Multinomial @@ Sow[k], {k, indexes}]]]
```

The inclusion of `Sow` and `Reap` (which can readily be removed after testing is complete) provides a method to monitor the calculation: each set of indexes is saved by `Sow` and all are returned via `Reap` after the calculation is complete.

**Examples**

```
f[5, 4, Range[0, 5]] (* Reproduce the preceding example *)
```

> $\{126,\{\{\{5,0,0,0\},\{4,1,0,0\},\{3,2,0,0\},\{3,1,1,0\},\{2,2,1,0\},\{2,1,1,1\}\}\}\}$

It obtains the same answer of $126$, followed by the detailed list of indexes contributing to that value.

```
f[8, 4, {1, 2, 4, 5}]
```

> $\{3696,\{\{\{5,1,1,1\},\{4,2,1,1\},\{2,2,2,2\}\}\}\}$

The indexes clearly are limited to the set $\{1,2,4,5\}$ in this calculation.  Without that limitation, we would invoke `f[8, 4, Range[0,8]]`, obtaining $8143$ instead of $3696$; $15$ different index vectors contribute to this sum.

Comment: thank you, I also do need a variation of that. Do you have an idea how to get only that coefficients where $k_i$ is not 0. In your example above it would be just the last term $\binom{5}{1\ 1\ 1\ 2}$?

Comment: It's even simpler: $(1\ 1\ 1\ 2)$ is the output of `IntegerPartitions[5, {4}]`.  In other words, there's no need to add `n` to `m` and afterwards subtract $1$ from each member of the partition.  An expression like `Total[Multinomial @@@ IntegerPartitions[m, {n}]]]` should work fine.

Comment: Thank you. But it's actually more complicated. I'm still not 100% sure if i got how one calculates the sum. I updated my question. I think it means that if $L=(1,2,4,5)$ that the third element can be zero. I'm sorry I haven't seen such a notation.

Comment: Your modification to the question does not make sense because it is now internally contradictory or ambiguous.  If, for example, "the third element can be zero," that doesn't add any restrictions to the $k_i$.  If it means the third element *must* be zero, then obviously the first two elements must be zero as well, so you might as well just forget about them and reduce $n$ by $3$ and use the existing solution. It sounds to me like you need to return to your references and research exactly what your problem is so that you can communicate it adequately.

Comment: I does not make sense to me either, until now I haven't seen  such an expression. These sum is an input into another function. I wrote down exactly how it is formulated in the paper. I'm sorry

Comment: Do you at least have some examples of computed values that could be used to check any solution?  (I would guess that "$\text{supp}(L)$" refers to the set of possible values allowed for the $k_i$.  You should be able to confirm such a guess based on the context of the paper.)

Comment: No unfortunately not. Its my job to do de computation and provide numerical examples. The only "external" information is that i am given the number $m$ and that $L\subseteq \{1,...,n\}$.I think I'll need to think it through once more, maybe I'll understand what's meant then.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be writing a tortured definition.

- As already commented you need `Pattern` in the left-hand-side of the definition.
- There are better tools than `For` in nearly all cases.
- `Return` is misapplied and unnecessary.
- As far as I can tell `Total` is dropped into the middle of things with no particular consideration.

You probably want something like this:

```
L = {1, 2, 4, 5};

f[m_, L_] := Sum[Multinomial @@ Take[L, i], {i, m}]

f[3, L]
```

> ```
> 109
> ```

Answer (score 2):

(This was supposed to be a comment, but it got too long.)

whuber's solution is nice, but I believe it can be compacted quite a fair bit:

```
g[n_Integer, m_Integer] := Sum[Multinomial @@ PadRight[ip, m],
                               {ip, IntegerPartitions[n, m]}]
```

As he notes in his answer, you can restrict the summation to nonnegative `m`-partitions of `n`. However, since `IntegerPartitions[]` returns only positive partitions, the way to go about it is to allow $1,2,\dots m$ partitions, and use `PadRight[]`  to tack on the needed zeroes before applying `Multinomial[]` and summing.

In trying to write a version where the partitions are restricted, I seem to be unable to reproduce whuber's results:

```
Select[IntegerPartitions[8, 4], VectorQ[#, MatchQ[#, 1 | 2 | 4 | 5] &] &]
   {{5, 2, 1}, {5, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4}, {4, 2, 2}, {4, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}
```

where it would seem that all of these partitions satisfy the constraint that the components lie in the set `{1, 2, 4, 5}`, but only a few of these are counted in whuber's solution.

In any event, here's how to write a restricted partition version:

```
g[n_Integer, m_Integer, idx : {__Integer}] := 
  Sum[Multinomial @@ PadRight[ip, m],
      {ip, Select[IntegerPartitions[n, m],
                  VectorQ[#, MatchQ[#, Alternatives @@ idx] &] &]}]
```

Test:

```
g[8, 4, {1, 2, 4, 5}]
   4354

Total[Multinomial @@ PadRight[#, 4] & /@
      {{5, 2, 1}, {5, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4}, {4, 2, 2}, {4, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}}]
   4354
```