# Problem with creating a large list of tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

This is a follow-up question from [Sum of Multinomial Coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19617/sum-of-multinomial-coefficients)

I have thought about the meaning of the formula I mentioned and, with help, I implemented the following code:

```
supp[vec_] := Module[{support = {}, i},
  Do[If[vec[[i]] != 0, AppendTo[support, i]], {i, 1, Length[vec]}];
  support
];

calctrafo[n_, func_] := Module[{vecs, trafo = 0, i},
  vecs = Tuples[Range[0, (n - 1)], n];
  vecs = Select[vecs, Total[#] == (n - 1) &];
  Do[trafo += (Multinomial @@ vecs[[i]])*func[supp[vecs[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[vecs]}];
  trafo
];

calctrafo[7, func]
```

The function `supp` gives me the support of the lists and `func` is a arbitrary function. This code works well for me, but I need the code to work for large `n`, `n >= 100`. The problem lies in the function `Tuples`, which crashes for `n > 6`. Is there a way to make this work for large `n`?

Comment: As I understand you the problem is that your very large result list from tuples will not fit in memory. If that is the case, you could perhaps use an iterative approach and something like http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/lazy-lists-of-tuples-and-subsets

Comment: @jVincent Thanks for the Link. But do I miss something, because I tried the first code in your answer but that it did not work.

Comment: There was a syntax change in the length test. You should be able to run it now.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my code and tried to create the tuples "on the fly" but for let's say for `Tuples[Range[0,20],19]` I loop through all possible Tuples. But there are approx. 19^20 Tuples and mathematica can't handle such a large number. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes. If you go from the code in that question you could simply do `allmyTuples=lazyTuples[Range@20,19];` which will not actually calculate them all yet, then if you call for instance `allmyTuples[[21312312841789283727]]` it will return only that one tuple, without having calculated all the others. If you want to iteraet over the tuples, the length can be found by calling `Length[allmyTuples]`.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but i need to apply a function to the every tuple, and if I loop through all tuples eg `Do[func[lazyTuples[Range@20,19][[i]]],{i,1,19^20}]`. Mathematica tells me it can't evaluate it.

Comment: You misspelled the function. It's `LazyTuple` not `LazyTuples`, and while such an evaluation will take quite a while to finish due to the `37,589,973,457,545,958,193,355,601` iterations it needs to go through, it should be possible as long as you are not using up to much memory in your `func` calls. I would suggest you start out trying to calculate how long it should approximately take before just blindly running the code and waiting though.

Comment: I think my function is really using to much memory because I get the following error `Do::iterb: "Iterator {i,1,(n-1)^(n+1)} does not have appropriate bounds"`.  I looking for all tuples Tuples`[Range[0,n],(n-1)] where the sum is equal to (n-1), calculate with these the Multinomial Coefficient and apply a function. Since I don't have any cs background I thought I seek help from you guys.

Comment: That error message seems to suggest that you haven't defined `n` meaning that the iterator doesn't have appropriate bounds since it doesn't know what `(n-1)^(n+1)` is. You should make sure you have set `n` to a value when you do this loop.

Comment: No, actually n has a value: `n = 20;
Do[tmp = lazyTuple[Range[0, n], (n - 1)][[i]];
 If[Total[tmp] == (n - 1), 
  Print[(Multinomial @@ tmp)*func[supp[tmp]]]], {i, 
  1, (n + 1)^(n - 1)}]` `(*20 Do::iterb...*)` where supp is the function provided by Simon Woods

Comment: Ahh, seems that by "inappropriate" it means that the bound is to large. It works up to `n=16` so it's properly just to large for it to work with. Try running a while loop instead, and again I would advice trying to estimate total run time by running a smaller number of iterations.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of creating a list of all tuples and then selecting those whose total is `n-1`, you could start with the `IntegerPartitions` of `n-1`, pad them to length `n` with zeroes, and create all the permutations:

```
getvecs[n_] := Flatten[Permutations[PadRight[#, n]] & /@ IntegerPartitions[n - 1], 1]
```

I would also suggest using `Position` for the support function:

```
supp2[vec_] := Flatten @ Position[Unitize @ vec, 1]
```

and replacing the `Do` loop with `Dot`:

```
calctrafo2[n_, func_] := With[{vecs = getvecs[n]},
  (Multinomial @@@ vecs).(func[supp2[#]] & /@ vecs)]
```

This is considerably faster:

```
Timing[calctrafo[7, Total]]
(*  {4.375, 1987804}  *)

Timing[calctrafo2[7, Total]]
(*  {0.031, 1987804}  *)
```

Comment: Nice work! (But you don't need me to tell you that, do you.)

Comment: Good point @Mr.Wizard. Oh, and congratulations on passing 50k!

Comment: Thank you. Truly nice performance improvement! For the code to work for large `n`, I think I need to think about an iterative approach